# How can multiple columns from different levels be selected?

Tags: python, pandas, select, multiple-columns, hierarchical-data

The dataframe below is a multi-indexed dataframe with hierarchical columns (df):

```
                   EMG                                     Biofeedback    
Time     ID  
                   delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma  HeartRateVariabilty GSR     
20170101 PD102       4     5     8    3         0     9                1        2 
20170102 PD102       5     7     8    4         6     5                2        3
```

How can multiple columns from different levels be selected? For e.g How can i get the dataframe showing all the **EMG columns** and only the **GSR column** under the **Biofeedback column** (as below)

```
                   EMG                                     Biofeedback    
Time     ID  
                   delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma   GSR     
20170101 PD102       4     5     8    3         0     9      2       
20170102 PD102       5     7     8    4         6     5      3
```

Comment: Do you have the code that generates this dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to access/subselect Hierarchical columns

**1.** Using `get_level_values` of first level and reject `HeartRateVariabilty`

```
In [764]: df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1) != 'HeartRateVariabilty']
Out[764]:
                 EMG                                  Biofeedback
               delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma         GSR
Time     ID
20170101 PD102     4     5     8    3         0     9           2
20170102 PD102     5     7     8    4         6     5           3
```

**2.** Or, Using `select` and reject `HeartRateVariabilty` in first level

```
In [765]: df.select(lambda x: x[1] != 'HeartRateVariabilty', axis=1)
Out[765]:
                 EMG                                  Biofeedback
               delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma         GSR
Time     ID
20170101 PD102     4     5     8    3         0     9           2
20170102 PD102     5     7     8    4         6     5           3
```

**3.** Or, Using `drop` and reject `HeartRateVariabilty` in first level

```
In [766]: df.drop('HeartRateVariabilty', axis=1, level=1)
Out[766]:
                 EMG                                  Biofeedback
               delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma         GSR
Time     ID
20170101 PD102     4     5     8    3         0     9           2
20170102 PD102     5     7     8    4         6     5           3
```

**4.** Or, Sub-select list of columns-pairs tuples with `.loc`

```
In [777]: cols = [('EMG', 'delta'), ('EMG', 'theta'), ('EMG', 'alpha'), ('EMG', 'beta'),
                  ('EMG', 'high beta'), ('EMG', 'gamma'), ('Biofeedback', 'GSR')]
In [778]: df.loc[:, cols]
Out[778]:
                 EMG                                  Biofeedback
               delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma         GSR
Time     ID
20170101 PD102     4     5     8    3         0     9           2
20170102 PD102     5     7     8    4         6     5           3
```

Comment: thanks! Solution 4 worked best for me as i required multiple columns under Biofeedback that is GSR and another (not inc the example!). Just for my informaion, is it possible to drop or reject multiple columns using solutions 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: Yes, as a list, and have `x not in [..]` condition where required.